# How to pass additional Hidden variable to jQuery/Ajax Post dataObj?

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsp

Friends

I have the following jQuery ajax Post call

```
function submitForm() {
             var selectedPricingTierId = "";
             var lstIds = new Array();

               jQuery('input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
                   if(this.checked && this.id !="select_all"){
                   if(selectedPricingTierId == "") {
                        selectedPricingTierId = this.id;
                    } else {
                        selectedPricingTierId = selectedPricingTierId + "," + this.id;
                    }

               }
                });

            var dataObj = {
                    "lstIds" : selectedPricingTierId
                };
                jQuery.ajax({
                    url : getCurrentLocation() + "/saveIncentives.action",
                    type : "POST",
                    data : dataObj,
                    success : function(data) {
                    closeWindow();

                    }
                });
            }
```

Now I have to pass the following  hidden variables to my dataObj

```
<s:hidden name="month" id="month" value="%{month}" />
<s:hidden name="year" id="year" value="%{year}" />
```

I'm clueless on how to append above hidden variables to my DataObj in Post call.

Please suggest a suitable way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
var dataObj = {};
dataObj.lstIds = selectedPricingTierId;
dataObj.month = $('input[name="month"]').val();
dataObj.year = $('input[name="year"]').val();
```

or:

```
var dataObj = {
    "lstIds" : selectedPricingTierId,
    "month" : $('input[name="month"]').val(),
    "year" : $('input[name="year"]').val()
};
```

That equals to the same.

But I would reccomend changing your approach to creating a form and then serializing it, and passing those serialized data to your ajax.

Here's the fiddle: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9339xkze/1/) and sample code:

```
<form id="myForm" action="saveIncentives.action" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="name" value="John" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike" />Bike
    <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car" />Car 
    <input type="hidden" name="month" value="04" />
    <input type="hidden" name="year" value="2015" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

and JS to serialize data:

```
$('#myForm').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var dataObj = $('#myForm').serialize();

    jQuery.ajax({
        url : $(this).attr('action'),
        type : "POST",
        data : dataObj,
        success : function(data) {
            closeWindow();
        }
    });

    return false;
});
```

This serialized data can be than easily read on server side just like you do with any POST parameters.

Comment: Thanks 
So my dataObj looks like 

var dataObj = {
                    "lstIds" : selectedPricingTierId,
     dataObj.month = $('input[name="month"]').val();
     dataObj.year = $('input[name="year"]').val();
                };  ??
Please let me know

Comment: No, if you want it this way than it should look like this: dataObj = { "lstIds" : selectedPricingTierId, "month" : $('input[name="month"]').val(), "year" : $('input[name="year"]').val() };

Comment: I've updated an answer for you to see better with code highlighting. If that helped please accept/vote an answer :)

Comment: Thanks Mate , appreciate the answer